# WooCommerce API creates images in media even if they exist

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

What might be a reason?
Trying to batch update product images (and price) in WooCommerce via REST API. Images already exist in wordpress media library and links are correctly copied. However, instead of using image it creates new image.

Request: POST.
URL: https://SiteURL/wp-json/wc/v2/products/xxxx?consumer_key=c______&consumer_secret=_____

Body:

```
 {"update":[
      {"regular_price":"448",
         "images":[
             {"src":"https://urlToImage.jpg",
               "position":0, "name": "test"}
      ],"id":"xxxx"}]}
```

In response I can see it creates image with the same url but as there is already an image in the library, it adds -1 to url.

Thank you in forward :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since this is an update where the images already exists you need to set the id member of the images element. Otherwise, WooCommerce interprets this as a request to add a new image to the product gallery.

Comment: Thanks heaps, this was extremely helpful

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more...Im confronted with the same issue.....where do you set the id elements of the images? FYI I have a syntax running in R whihc uplaods images perfectly via POST /wp/v2/media/......however when I try to use POST /wp/v2/media/<id> (so with id of the current image pasted behind it)...the syntax runs without error but the images are not updated